# How to install, compile, and utilize Rebar in Windows 8

Tags: windows, erlang, rebar

Is this possible?

All tutorials I've come across on how to build and use Rebar involve Unix commands, and I'm a most unfortunate Windows user. I'd really like to avoid installing Cygwin if I can help it.

For example, to build Rebar you get:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/rebar/rebar.git
$ cd rebar
$ ./bootstrap
Recompile: src/getopt
...
Recompile: src/rebar_utils
==> rebar (compile)
Congratulations! You now have a self-contained script called "rebar" in
your current working directory. Place this script anywhere in your path
and you can use rebar to build OTP-compliant apps.
```

**What is the windows-cmd equivalent?**

Any links or tutorial below to offer step by step instructions on how to utilize rebar in windows shell would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

After manually downloading and extracting Rebar to my directory located at:
C:\erlang\rebar

I go to the windows shell and enter:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\erl5.10.1\bin
```

This is the 'bin' folder located inside the directory holding erlang.exe

Next I enter:

```
C:\erlang\rebar>bootstrap.bat
```

Compiled! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There should be a `bootstrap.bat` script in the rebar directory.  You don't need cygwin for this to work, but you will need Erlang installed and on the path.

Comment: You do, however, need everything to compile the rebar dependencies. Bootstrap will only give you the rebar script - which will then fetch and try to compile (often linux) dependencies. This is where I got stuck. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have [erlang](http://erlang.org/download.html) istalled already and added to your path.

You can just download the [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and install it. Then open the git bash and type

- `git clone https://github.com/rebar/rebar.git`
- once cloned it to your desired location then you can run the command by going inside the rebar directory.

  ./bootstrap
- Now it will work just fine and tell you that you have the rebar file compiled in your current working directory.

Nice you are good to go with using rebar for your project.

Comment: This wasn't even an option -- or an otherwise unknown option -- when I asked this question in 2013... Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just invoke *path\to\erlang-install\bin*\escript.exe **bootstrap** from a (Windows) command shell.

*bootstrap* is just an e(rlang) script.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)
Then, use it to run the same exact instructions:

```
git clone git://github.com/rebar/rebar.git
cd rebar
./bootstrap
```

and everything should work fine.